# Cálculo de variaciones

Tags: python, pandas

He intentado hacer un calculo de variaciones de un precio a distintas fechas, para eso cargo un archivo y luego creo listas distintas para editarlas y dejarlas con la misma longitud para calcular la diferencia de precio entre un día u otro. creo una lista3 vacía que es donde quiero tener la diferencia de precios. ME funciona cuando  la diferencia de días representada por d es igual a 0 o igual a 1, pero no en el resto de casos.

Con este código ok, si de = a 0 o a 1

```
import pandas as pd
pd.options.display.max_rows =10
ruta=r'C:\Users\COtero\Desktop\Evolucion Eurostoxx.csv'
eurostoxx_dataframe = pd.read_csv(ruta, sep=";")
d = 1
lista1 = eurostoxx_dataframe['Precio']*1
lista2 = eurostoxx_dataframe['Precio']*1
lista3 = []
while d >=1:
    d = d-1
    lista2.pop(0)
    finlista= len(lista1)-1 
    lista1.pop(finlista)
for a,b in zip(lista1,lista2):
    lista3.append(((b/a)-1)*100)    

eurostoxx_dataframe.describe()
datos_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(lista3)
datos_dataframe.describe()
print(lista1)
print(lista2)
print(lista3)
```

Si por el contrario d=2 o más me da el siguiente error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He probado otras cosas, como la que pongo pero sigo sin conseguir nada:

```
#importo bibliotecas
import pandas as pd
#defino las rutas de los archivos que voy a usar
ruta=r'C:\Users\COtero\Desktop\Evolucion Eurostoxx.csv'
#creo un dataframe con esos datos que he importado en las rutas
df = pd.read_csv(ruta, sep=";")
#creo 2 nuevas listas quitando en ambas la columnas de la fecha y hago una 
solo con la columna de las fechas
lista1=df.drop(['Fecha'], axis=1)
lista2=df.drop(['Fecha'], axis=1)
lista3=df.drop(['Precio'], axis=1)
#elimino el numero de dias para hacer listas 
dias = 10
iniciolista1=0
finlista2 =len(lista2)
while dias >=1:
    dias = dias-1
    finlista2 = finlista2 -1
    lista1= lista1.drop([iniciolista1],axis=0)
    lista2= lista2.drop([finlista2],axis=0)
    lista3= lista3.drop([iniciolista1],axis=0)
    iniciolista1 = iniciolista1 +1
#Pongo que las listas sea de caracter float para poder realizar operaciones 
sin problema.
lista1['Precio'] = lista1['Precio'].astype(float)    
lista2['Precio'] = lista1['Precio'].astype(float)  
#lista3['variaciones'] = lista3['variaciones'].astype(float)    
#for a,b in zip(lista1,lista2):
#    lista3.append(((b/a)-1)*100)
#cambio el nombre de las columnas para ponerlas como precio incial y precio 
final
precio_inicial = lista2.rename(columns ={'Precio':'Precio inicial'})
precio_final = lista1.rename(columns ={'Precio':'Precio final'})
#precio_final.describe()
#print(precio_inicial)
#print(precio_final)
precios = pd.merge( precio_inicial, precio_final, left_on='Precio inicial', 
right_on='Precio final')
print(precios)
```

me salen los datos como si no hubiera realizado ningun cambio y me aparecen mas filas de las que deberian:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

CReo que es un error de concepto. Si alguien me pudiera ayudar. Un saludo

Comment: Hola, bienvenidx a Stack Overflow. Por favor, incluye tu código como texto, así como los mensajes obtenidos, los errores, los datos de prueba y la salida esperada

Answer (score 0):

Sin tener el csv de ejemplo no sabría darte más detalle, pero el problema que tienes es el que Python te describe con KeyError.

Hace un bucle while que mientras d = 1 solo se ejecuta una vez, pero el problema no es ese. El problema es que haces `pop` a cada elemento de lista2, y eso lo que hace es "quitarlo". Lo que al final ocurre es que dejas lista2 vacía y cuando vuelve a ejecutarse el bucle while por segunda vez (si d = 2) la lista está vacía y por lo tanto no puede hacer `pop` porque no tiene ningún elemento.

No termino de entender por qué quieres quitarle elementos a la lista. Quizás una muestra del dataframe sea más concluyente

En segundo lugar puedes evitar declarar de antemano lista3 con una comprensión de lista, es más legible:

```
for a,b in zip(lista1,lista2):
lista3.append(((b/a)-1)*100) 

Es igual a...

lista3 = [ ((b/a)-1) * 100 for a, b in zip(lista1, lista2)
```